# cron en un dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, cron, crontab, cronjobs

Me delegaron una tarea de devops, tengo que ejecutar un script de python cada 3 horas, el script esta en una imagen de docker, mi idea es meter cron en el `dockerfile` (no se me ocurre como hacerlo), que es el siguiente:

```bash
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /home/connectPY/dockerfile1
AND . .
RUN pip install pymssql
RUN pip install pandas
RUN  pip install sqlAlchemy
RUN pip install mysql
RUN pip install pymysql
CMD ["script.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

Si alguien tiene una idea o sabe como hacerlo seria genial, estuve viendo tutoriales pero no encuentro uno que me funcione

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Buenas!

En el DockerFile puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Actualizas repos

> RUN apt-get update

- instalas en cron dentro del container

> RUN apt-get -y install cron

-especificas que quieres ejecutar y cuando

> RUN crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * bash /root/get_date.sh"; } |
> crontab -

- Ejecutas cron al inicio del container

> CMD cron

Nota* Esto lo he sacado de baeldung, te dejo link al original:
https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-cron-job

Comment: gracias! al final agregue una funcion al propio codigo de python para que el mismo lo haga